Excel Worksheet.Change Event behavior when deleting a row
All,
I am trying to understand how Excel Worksheet.Change event would behave when a row is deleted. Below are the worksheet and the event handler:
Beginning Data on the worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim msg As String

    For Each Cell In Target
        msg = msg & " " & Cell.Value
    Next Cell

     MsgBox Target.Address & vbCrLf & msg

End Sub

When I delete Row 6, the following MsgBox shows:

MsgBox when Row 6 is deleted

My question at this point is: in addition to Row 6, shouldn't Target include Row 7 & 8 as well as their values are changed too? (Row 7 is replaced with data from original Row 8, and Row 8 now has become blank?)

Click OK on the MsgBox and do a CTRL+Z, A new MsgBox shows up:
New event triggered after Ctrl + Z:


Same question as above. Two rows have been pushed down, but not included in Target as part of changed range?

Click OK again,  the event handler is triggered again. But no idea what might have caused it
Event Handler invoked again for no apparent reason?

Any help is appreciated!
Have been trying to search for similar questions online, but couldn't find anything I feel is comparable.

Please don't post images of error messages. Type the mesaage in as text.

Target only includes cells whose values were changed/replaced/deleted.  It doesn't include cells which were moved but whose values were not changed.

@TimWilliams Thank you Tim. This could explain the first and second MsgBox. I couldn't find any documentation that gives a clear definition on what constitutes a change. Any idea about the last MsgBox? Thank you again.

I can't account for that second msgbox after the Undo.

@TimWilliams thanks. How do I give u at least some sort of recognition for your help? I remember there used to be an option to at least upvote a comment.

No need - hope you were able to figure out the rest.
